# How to Pass Original Value of Array Item after using Matcher and regex

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-spinner

So In my app I have a few spinners the one spinner gives a Hourly Rate,

the data in the spinner I have edited using Matcher,regex etc. so that they display correctly in the spinner

but what I can't figure out is I have to pass the original string of the Array Item on item select to a URL builder And I have No Idea how to do this at all and have googled for hours now

so the original
object looks like this

```
7 - 1 - R100
```

so I used Matcher and Pattern to trim that value in the spinner to display just

```
R100
```

But now I have to pass the original value of

```
7 - 1 - R100
```

To a URI Builder

Here is the code for populating the spinner

```
 private void LoadUserRatesSpinnerData(String url) {


           RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");
                            for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String rates=jsonObject1.getString("UserRate");

                          for(int p=0; p < 100; p++){
                                    final Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(" - ").matcher(rates);
                                    if (matcher.find()) {
                                        rates=rates.substring(matcher.end()).trim();
                                    }
                                }

                                UserRate.add(rates);



                            }
                        }
                        UserRatesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(IntTimeLog.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, UserRate));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            int socketTimeout=30000;
            RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

The onItemSelected code for the spinner

```
      UserRatesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    UserRatesSpinner.setClickable(true);
                } else {
                    UserRatesSpinner.setClickable(true);
                    UserRates=UserRatesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }
                if (LogHour.getText().toString().contains("Hours Logged")) {
                    LogHour.setText("Log Hours");
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
```

At the Moment only the R100 gets passed to the URI builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this Issue by making another ArrayList and adding the original Json data before I adding the data from the matcher to a seprate arraylist,

**Here is the code**

```
 private void LoadTaskSpinner(String url) {
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(IntTimeLog.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait..Loading Time Log Data");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.show();
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
pd.cancel();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");
                        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String task=jsonObject1.getString("TaskName");
                            TaskName.add(task);
                        }
                    }
                    taskSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(IntTimeLog.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, TaskName));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.cancel();
               LoadErrorSpinner(ClientsUrl);
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout=30000;
        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

And then in the Item selection I used IF statements to get the correct String to the URL

```
UserRatesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        if (position == 1) {
            SelectedSpin = ItemSelect.get(1);

        }
        else{
            UserRatesSpinner.setClickable(true);

        }
        if (position == 2) {
            SelectedSpin = ItemSelect.get(2);

        }
        else {
            UserRatesSpinner.setClickable(true);

        }
        if (position == 3) {
            SelectedSpin = ItemSelect.get(3);
        }
        else{
            UserRatesSpinner.setClickable(true);
        }

        if (LogHour.getText().toString().contains("Hours Logged")) {
            LogHour.setText("Log Hours");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a new variable, I called it `trimmedRates`. As it stands your code is overwriting the variable `rates`.

```
String trimmedRates;   
     if (matcher.find()) {
                           trimmedRates=rates.substring(matcher.end()).trim();
                         }
```

Comment: so how can I pass the original value to a URI.Builder then, What I want is the Spinner Must Display the trimmed rates, but when one is selected in the spinner it must pass the original(Not trimmed) value to the URI.Builder